# Collection view spacing

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am developing an App that uses a collectionview. Currently right now I am trying to have my spacing set up with 4 items per row, and 2 rows. The 4x2 grid will always be shown and I want the boxes to size to fit within the rectangle. However, it seems to always run the wrong sizes.

Here is my code below.

```
let numberOfItemPerRow: CGFloat = 4
let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 2
        
let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 2
let height = myCollectionView.frame.height / 2 - 5
let width = (view.frame.width - (numberOfItemPerRow - 1) * interItemSpacing) / numberOfItemPerRow
     
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = lineSpacing
MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interItemSpacing
        
myCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(MyCollectionViewFlowLayout, animated: true)`
```

Also Here is an image of what I'm going for.
[image]

Comment: Do you always have 8 items? If so, maybe `UIStackView` is a better idea?

Comment: yes always 8 items, and i've built most of the infastructure around collectionview, so if possible a cv solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine. Check the below screenshot. Please elaborate on the wrong size you are observing.
[image]